# Naming convention in Java EE project

Tags: java, javascript, jakarta-ee, struts2

I am using Struts 2 framework. I am coming across this practice which I don't know is right or wrong.

My function name for a particular action is say: `getTspList` in Action class.
Then to serve this action in my bean I have the function which gets my data from DB. To name this function in my bean I using same function name `getTspList` . Then in my JavaScript file also if I am getting data via AJAX, same function name is being used.

So Action class, Bean , JavaScript file same function name `getTspList`. Is this a Bad practice?

If yes, how to put different names??

**EDIT**: Actually my own written `getXYZ`/`setXYZ` for a variable `XYZ` in which I `get`/`set` them through calls to the bean, clash with the `getter`/`setter` for that member variable of my class.

How to come up with a solution to this?

Comment: it doesn't look bad but I'm not sure what TSP is. if it is some business entity then its fine to use it across. But be careful wtih `public get...()` methods in action classes because they will be called if you use the variables in jsp .. i.e. if your getTspList has a DB call and you use `<s:property value="tspList" />` in your jsp then you might unintentionally do a database call there.

Comment: @ArvindSridharan: Yeah was about to mention that, that it clashes with getter of the variable. Any idea to resolve this?

Comment: Use `find` and `add` so they won't clash :) by the way you shouldn't have these methods in Action but in another level, so your call would be `getService().getXYZ` and it won't clash the same.

Comment: @AndreaLigios: Another level ?? Can u explain more?

Comment: Can you post some minimal code pleasE ?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/namingconventions-139351.html) is naming conventions from oracle official site. Take a look at it.

Or you can refer this detailed [document](http://www.bahrain.bh/pubportal/wps/wcm/connect/690676004394686f843cbea42b14669a/Java_J2EE_Naming_Convention%28NEAF%29.pdf?MOD=AJPERES&CACHEID=690676004394686f843cbea42b14669a) .

Answer (score 0):

ITS BETTER TO USE `getTspListBean,getTspListJs,getTspListAcion` so we can easily understand

it is better to use either **camelcasing or pascal casing**

**camel casing** All the words start with capital and all other letters are small letter
**pascal casing** except the first word all others are in camel casing and first word begins with small letter.

in projects i use **camel casing for classes,interfaces**

and **all functions are written in pascal** casing.

Comment: Classes and interfaces should be written in [Pascal Case](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PascalCase), otherwise known as UpperCamelCase. Methods should be in camelCase, starting with a lower-case letter. That is the canonical Java naming convention, and that's what your getters follow as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `GoogleStyle` for formatting. Get that and import the xml file to your project and you are a GO.

As for the naming convention, **standard naming** convention is good although some companies use their own formatting and naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

To name your objects in Java you should comply to Java Bean conventions to name methods as a property accessors to Java bean properties. These methods are named with `get/set` prefixes.

If you name an action method like that it will be treated as a bean property and available to OGNL. If it has a `public` access modifier then regardless its purpose to be an action it could be used as a getter.

For example property `tspList` is accessible from the `valueStack` via OGNL because it has a getter `getTspList()`.

So, if you don't want such thing happen you should not map actions to the bean properties.